# I need help wrapping my head around the return statement with Python and its role in this recursive statement

Tags: python, recursion, printing, return

No this isn't homework but it is on our study guide for a test. I need to understand the role the return statement plays and the role recursion plays. I don't understand why the function doesn't break after x = 1.

```
def thisFunc(x):
    print(x)
    if x>1:
         result=thisFunc(x-1)
         print(result)
    return x+1
```

Sorry, I understand how elementary this is but I could really use some help. Probably why I can't find an explanation anywhere...because it's so simple.

edit: Why does it print out what it does and what and why is the value of x at the end? sorry if I'm asking a lot I'm just frustrated

Comment: There's also an error in your indentation, but that may be a typo in the question and not in the function as you are running it.

Comment: where is the error in indentation?

Comment: Draw a picture of the execution with a visual representation of the frames on the stack at each change. You can use a sequence of blocks...everytime thisFunc is called draw one more block for the new frame and everytime thisFunc returns a frame is popped off so you should draw one less.  Trace the execution through each invocation this way.  The function at no point "breaks" but you're not able to visualize the flow because it's expanding out rather than iterating in a flatter structure.  For way too much information on this kind of stuff look up SICP.

Comment: @Matt Whipple When I checked the function `thisFunc(1)` returns what I'd expect: 2

Answer (score 1):

When you enter the function with a value `n>1` it prints the current value, and then calls it's self with `n-1`.  When the inner function returns it returns the value `n - 1 + 1` which is just `n`.  Hence, the function prints out the value `n` twice, once before the inner recursion and once after.

If `n == 1`, which is the base case, the function only prints `1` once and does not call it self again (and hence does not get `result` back to print).  Instead it just returns, hence why `1` is only printed once.

Think of it like an onion.

calling `thisFunc(n)` will result in

```
n
# what ever the output (via print) of thisFunc(n-1) is
n
```

Answer (score 0):

*I don't understand why the function doesn't break after x = 1.*

But it does:

```
>>> ================================ RESTART ================================
>>> x = 1
>>> def thisFunc(x):
    print("Function called on x-value: ", x)
    if x > 1:
        result = thisFunc(x-1)
        print(result)
    return x+1

>>> thisFunc(x)
Function called on x-value:  1
2
>>>
```

*edit: Why does it print out what it does and what and why is the value of x at the end?*
Well, it prints it out because you're telling it to. Try following the value of x as you go through the function ("x is one, one is not *bigger* than 1; return 1+1. Ok. [new case] x is two, two is bigger than 1..." and so on).

`return` and `recursion` are part and parcel of programming; return statements designates the end of a function (even if you might have several lines more of code) and they also pass data back to whatever asked them for it. In your case you're asking "what happens when x is 1, given these rules?"; the returned data is your answer.

Recursion is simply the matter of letting the function call itself, should it (you) need to. You simply tell the program that "hey, as long as x is bigger than 1, call this function [that just so happens to be the same function initially called] on it and let it do its thing". To get a better understanding of your function I'd suggest that you add the line `"Function called on x-value: "` to the first `print` statement inside the function,  or at least something that lets you identify which printed line is `x` and which is `result`.

For a more in-depth explanation on recursion, I recommend [Recursion explained with the flood fill algorithm and zombies and cats](http://inventwithpython.com/blog/2011/08/11/recursion-explained-with-the-flood-fill-algorithm-and-zombies-and-cats/)